# how to specify the redirect url for the google sign-in button

Tags: oauth

i was wondering how to specify the redirect url for a google sign-in button, here is the button:

```
 <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Param name is **data-redirecturi**. Example:

```
<div class="g-signin2" 
   data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
   data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
   data-accesstype="offline"
   data-redirecturi="https://www.example.com/redirect_uri"></div>
```

Note that you don't have to set *data-cookiepolicy*, it's *single_host_origin* by default.

Comment: thank you for the answer ,it works ,but it redirects the popup of the authentification not the page where there is the sign-in button , is there any way to make it do so?

Comment: Try changing data-redirecturi to "postmessage". With that you should receive access_code in data-onsuccess callback.

Comment: @JarosławGomułka Could you explain or at least refer to what data-accesstype and redirecturl does?

Answer (score 0):

**I believe Google changed this a while ago.**

What I used to redirect:

```
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '615643915869-vufkml5ogm4j4a01qbshk9darkhq7vpr.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    fetch_basic_profile: true,
    ux_mode: redirect,
    redirect_uri: ''
  });

  auth2.signIn().then(() => {
    var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Google Sign Up or Login Error: ', error)
  });
});
```

The parameter `ux_mode` can be either 'popup' or 'redirect'.
If the latter is chosen the parameter `redirect_uri` can take your url

> If using ux_mode='redirect', this parameter allows you to override the
>   default redirect_uri that will be used at the end of the consent flow.
>   The default redirect_uri is the current URL stripped of query
>   parameters and hash fragment.

Here is [Link to the Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2020, can you do it like this.
Documentation : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

```
function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'ux_mode': 'redirect',
        'redirect_uri': 'REDIRECT URL HERE',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

with this you can make that with the sign-in button of google

first call to the api sdk google script

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

then set the meta tag of you client id

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

and in the script of the button, set something like this:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" onclick="location.href='page url'"></div>
```

Comment: Since data-onsuccess already call  "onSignIn()"  you can add "document.location.href = ... " inside the onSignIn() function.