# I keep having to change window.location.href depending on whether i'm developing on localhost or pushing to the server

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using google sign in and that's working. Once signed in I've got some code in app.js that opens a new webpage using:

```
window.location.href
```

But if I'm developing then the webpage is at:

```
localhost:3000/webpage.html
```

But then the `URL` changes when I push to the server.

Is there a way to use `"or"` so it will open on the `localhost` or on the server depending on where this is hosted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: **Use relative links.**
Simply strip the host part from urls in your JavaScript file, like this:

**From**:

```
http://example.com/yourpage.htm
```

**To**:

```
/yourpage.htm
```

Now it will work, both locally and on your production server.

When you set '`location.href`' to the relative url, the browser will add the current host name to the url.

Answer (score 2):

**Relative Paths**

You might be asking about relative paths. A relative path doesn't contain the main [domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hostname), it only includes the path.

Instead of using:
`localhost:3000/webpage.html`

You could use: `/webpage.html`

Learn more about absolute vs. relative paths [here](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

**Google Sign In**

Alternatively, if the question is about how to redirect to the public url (a .com address instead of localhost) when in production, [take a look at this already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333870/how-to-specify-the-redirect-url-for-the-google-sign-in-button).