# How can I redirect users to a new page after they logged in with the Google login form?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-signin

I'm using the google login button for my web app. After login, I want to redirect the logged in users to a new page. I can't seem to get the redirect to work.

As a replacement, I made a setTimeOut function that triggers when the login button is pressed. So after a few seconds, the users get redirected. But when the network is a bit delayed, users get redirected even if the login isn't completed yet.

I also tried making an if else statement that if the login was succesfull that it can trigger the setTimeOut function. But that doesn't seem to work either. I'm new to JS so my apologies for any obvious mistakes.

```
  <script>
     function delayFunction() {
       setTimeout("location.href = 'here comes the redirect url';");
     }

     function doNothing() {

     }
  </script>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="user"><a href="/pages/profile.php"><p id="name"></p></a></div>
            <div class="headtitle">
                <div class="loginpage">
                  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" onclick="setTimeout(delayFunction, 3500)"></div>
                    <div class="of"><p>Or:</p></div>
                      <div class="buttonWebsite">Go to our website</div>

   <script>
      if (onSignIn = true) {
       setTimeout(delayFunction, 3500)
      } else {
       doNothing()
      }
    </script>
```

If I want to run the if statement, I delete the onclick="setTimeOut" to test etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to specify the redirect url for the google sign-in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333870/how-to-specify-the-redirect-url-for-the-google-sign-in-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the data-attribute `data-onsuccess` what it does it. it will look for a function named `onSignIn` ( as specified as its value)  and executes it

make a function like this

```
<script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

      window.location = '<redirect_url>'
      }
    </script>
```

check out this link for more info : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

authenticating the generated token in the backend : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: I got that function already, but I didn't want to post every single line of code of my file. But do you have any idea what the next step will be? To redirect users to a new page after te login is succesfull?